# Ansible remove/change lines with star sign in playbook execution output

Tags: ansible

I want to control number of stars(*) ansible playbook output displays for every task execution.

Example:

```
  PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************

  TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [include_vars] ******************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]
```

I wan to control number of stars get printed here. Is there a simple solution like adding an entry to config file or something without changing ansible code?

I wan to print something like

```
  PLAY [localhost] *************************************

  TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [include_vars] *********************************************************
  ok: [localhost]
```

I am trying to control the output so that it fits a small terminal screen

Answer (score 5):

This is how things look like under the hood:

```
self.columns = max(79, tty_size - 1)
```

So you either get tty_size if it is wide enough, or default 79 if tty_size is smaller than that.

To overcome this you can drop this code as `callback_plugins/crop_columns.py`:

```
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase

try:
    from __main__ import display
except ImportError:
    display = None


class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if display is not None:
            display.columns = 50
```

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin Suvorov. We need to change ansible code for this right? Do you think we can apply this to already installed ansible software ?

Comment: No need to change code. You can distribute plugins within project's structure. So put this code to `/path/to/playbook/callback_plugins/crop_columns.py`.

Comment: I'd like to entirely remove the stars/asterisks. Setting `display.columns` to `0` only results in a reduction to three asterisks, as the `banner` method sets `star_len` to a minimum of `3`. Do you know if a callback can be used to avoid any asterisks being output?

Comment: @DavidOliver writing `display.columns = 0` makes my Ansible crash in the mid of my playbook: `ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: invalid width 0 (must be > 0)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in ansible 2.13.5. I know this used to work, but recently I tried it again, and it doesn't seem to be cropping any of the asterisks.

Comment: I can confirm that this code use to work but now it doesn't. I am at 2.13.3 and this doesn't work. For my case, since i am using `InventoryModule`, it was easy for me to set column width by simply doing `self.display.columns = 120` in module's init function.

Comment: See also:  https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/use-ansibles-yaml-callback-plugin-better-cli-experience